# Black panther, dark night, mysterious episode of TV Series

Tags: story-identification, tv

It was an episode of an unknown TV series or something in the style of "Are You Afraid of the Dark?", probably from the 90's. I'm almost sure that it's a TV series from the 90's. I remember only the ending scene: a black panther goes through the forest in a dark night. A long-haired man is scared, but when the wild cat is very near him, the man shouts: "Forgive me Father for I have sinned!" (several times). The black panther stops. The lector says: "The most important is humility!".

What is the name of this episode or movie?

Comment: What do you mean by "lector"? Do you mean a (voiceover) narrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's **"[An Eye for an Eye](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0939449/)"** (1993), S03E33 of *[Swamp Thing](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098919/?ref_=tt_ov_inf)* (1990–1993).

> When the swamp stalks Arcane in the form of a panther, an ecological message is the overtone about unsafe modes of power encroaching on nature and how she strikes back.

My memory wasn't exact - the panther isn't black.

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.